Is there an integer sequence $(k_n)$ where each term is non-zero such that $\lim z^{k_n}=1$ for every point z on the unit circle?
Is there an integer sequence $(k_n)$ where each term is non-zero such that $\lim z^{k_n}=1$ for every point $z$ on the unit circle of the complex plane? I don't think it exists，but I don't know how to prove it.

If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Assume that $(k_n)$ is a sequence of nonzero integers such that $z^{k_n}\to 1$ holds for every $z$ on the unit circle. Then, by the dominated convergence theorem,
$$\int_0^1 e^{2\pi itk_n}\,dt\to\int_0^1 1\,dt.$$
However, the left-hand side is $0$ for every $n$, while the right-hand side is $1$, which is a contradiction.

Let me prove slightly more: for every sequence $k=(k_n)$ of nonzero integers, the set
$$C_k=\{z\in \mathbf{U}:\lim_n z^{k_n}=1\}$$
has measure zero (so is not the whole unit circle $\mathbf{U}$).
Let $d$ be the geodesic distance on the circle and $\lambda$ its Lebesgue measure (normalized so that $\lambda(\mathbf{U})=2\pi$). Let $B_r$ be the $r$-ball $\{z\in\mathbf{U}:d(z,1)\le r\}$. Then for every $r\le\pi$ we have $\lambda(B_r)=2r$, and furthermore for every $m\in\mathbf{Z}-\{0\}$, we have $\lambda\{z:z^m\in B_r\}=2r$ (this just reflects that $z\mapsto z^m$ is measure-preserving).
We have $$\begin{align*}C_k=&\bigcap_{m\ge 1}\{z\in\mathbf{U}:\exists i\forall j\ge i:d(z^{k_j},1)\le 1/m\}\\ &=\bigcap_{m\ge 1}\bigcup_{i\ge 1}\bigcap_{j\ge i}K_{mij},\quad K_{mij}=\{z\in\mathbf{U}:d(z^{k_j},1)\le 1/m\}\end{align*}$$
Since $K_{mij}$ has measure $2/m$ (because $k_j\neq 0$), $K_{mi}=\bigcap_{j\ge i}K_{mij}$ has measure $\le 2/m$. Since the union $K_m=\bigcup_i K_{mi}$ is increasing, we deduce that $K_m$ has measure $\le 2/m$, and in turn $C_k$ has measure $\le 2/m$. Since this holds for all $m$, we deduce that $C_k$ has measure $0$.
